# C++: How to use Bubble Sort to Rearrange my Data

Tags: c++

The bubble sort is supposed to be based on the wages array. The employee id, the pay rate and the hours should change after the wages have been sorted in ascending order. I am able to sort the pay rate but my employee id information remains the same. Do I need another do while loop?

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// Constant for the array size.
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 4;

// Function Prototypes
void getEmployeeInfo(long [], int [], double [], double [], int);

void bubbleSort(long empId[],int hours[],double payRate[],double wages[],int size); 

void displayWages(long empId[], double wages[], int size);

int main()
{
    // Array of employee ID numbers
    long empId[ARRAY_SIZE] = { 5658845, 4520125, 7895122,
                               8777541};

    // Array to hold the hours worked for each employee
    int hours[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0};

    // Array to hold the hourly pay rate for each employee
    double payRate[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0};

    // Array to hold the gross wages for each employee
    double wages[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0};

    // Get the employee payroll information and store
    // it in the arrays.
    getEmployeeInfo(empId, hours, payRate, wages, ARRAY_SIZE);

    // Display the payroll information.
    displayWages(empId, wages, ARRAY_SIZE);

    // Sort the payroll information in ascending order with a bubble sort. 
    bubbleSort(empId, hours, payRate, wages, ARRAY_SIZE); 

    // Display the payroll information again. 
    displayWages (empId, wages, ARRAY_SIZE); 

    system("PAUSE"); 

    return 0;
}

// ********************************************************
// The getEmployeeInfo function receives four parallel    *
// arrays as arguments. The 1st array contains employee   *
// IDs to be displayed in prompts. It asks for input and  *
// stores hours worked and pay rate information in the    *
// 2nd and 3rd arrays. This information is used to        *
// calculate gross pay, which it stores in the 4th array. *
// ********************************************************
void getEmployeeInfo(long emp[], int hrs[], double rate[],
                     double pay[], int size)
{
    cout << "Enter the requested information "
         << "for each employee.\n";

    // Get the information for each employee.
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        cout << "\nEmployee #: " << emp[count] << "\t";

        // Get this employee's hours worked.
        cout << "Hours worked: ";
        cin  >> hrs[count];

        // Validate hours worked.
        while (hrs < 0)
        {
            cout << "\nHours worked must be 0 or more. "
                 << "Please re-enter: ";
            cin  >> hrs[count];
        }

        // Get this employee's pay rate.
        cout << "\tPay rate: $";
        cin  >> rate[count];

        // Validate the pay rate.
        while (rate[count] < 6.00)
        {
            cout << "\nPay rate must be 6.00 or more. "
                 << "Please re-enter: $";
            cin  >> rate[count];
        }

        // Calculate this employee's gross pay.
        pay[count] = hrs[count]*rate[count]; 

        // ADD statement to calculate wages by multiplying
                // hours with rate of pay;
    }
}

// ********************************************************
// The bubbleSort function sorts the information based on *
// the wages array.                                       *
// ********************************************************
void bubbleSort(long empId[],int hours[],double payRate[],double wages[],int size)
{
    bool swap; 
    int index; 

    do
    {
        swap = false; 
        for (int count = 0; count < (size - 1); count++)
        {
            if (wages[count] > wages [count + 1])
            {
                index = wages[count]; 
                wages[count] = wages[count + 1]; 
                wages[count + 1] = index; 
                swap = true; 
            }
        }

    } while (swap); 
}

// ********************************************************
// The displayWages function displays employee ID numbers *
// and their wages.                                       *
// ********************************************************
void displayWages(long empId[], double wages[], int size)
{
    // Set up the numeric output formatting.
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << endl;

    // Display the header.
    cout << "----------------------------\n";
    cout << "Employee               Wages\n";
    cout << "----------------------------\n\n";

    // Display each employee's pay.
    for (int count = 0; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count++)
    {
        cout << "Employee #" << empId[count] << "   $";
        cout << setw(7) << wages[count] << endl << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Inside your bubblesort function where you swap two elements of the wages array, you need to also swap the corresponding elements of the empId, hours and payRate arrays

Comment: So does that mean I should add 2 more if statements but have it correspond to the empId and hours?

Comment: no, because you are sorting based on wages, so the if statement should only compare the wages. I'll add an answer to show what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your bubbleSort function where you swap two elements of the wages array, you need to also swap the corresponding elements of the empId, hours and payRate arrays. Also, you need to use a the same types for the temporary swap variables as the values you are swapping or you will lose accuracy from converting to an int.

```
void bubbleSort(long empId[],int hours[],double payRate[],double wages[],int size)
{
    bool swap; 
    double temp1; 
    int temp2;
    long temp3;

    do
    {
        swap = false; 
        for (int count = 0; count < (size - 1); count++)
        {
            // compare the wages, because that is what you are sorting on
            if (wages[count] > wages [count + 1])
            {
                // swap all the data between the two array positions:
                temp1 = wages[count]; 
                wages[count] = wages[count + 1]; 
                wages[count + 1] = temp1; 

                temp1 = payRate[count]; 
                payRate[count] = payRate[count + 1]; 
                payRate[count + 1] = temp1;

                temp2 = hours[count]; 
                hours[count] = hours[count + 1]; 
                hours[count + 1] = temp2; 

                temp3 = empId[count]; 
                empId[count] = empId[count + 1]; 
                empId[count + 1] = temp3; 

                swap = true; 
            }
        }

    } while (swap); 
}
```

Comment: Okay. Thank you. This was so simple. I didn't think of just adding the statements inside the loop and thought to add more for loops.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember that the only thing connecting an employee id with a particular wage is that they are in the same position in the two arrays. So if you change one but not the other they will become out of sync and won't match any more. For this reason it's probably better to put all the information that goes together (id, wage etc) into a struct or class and have an array of structs instead of 4 separate arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Helper Function to Swap

```
void swaphelper(long (&emp)[] , doubles(&wages)[] ,doubles(&payrate)[] , int(&hours)[],  int fromIndex , int toIndex) 
{

   emp[fromIndex] = emp[fromIndex]^emp[toIndex];
   emp[toIndex] = emp[toIndex]^emp[fromIndex];

   wages[fromIndex] = wages[fromIndex]^wages[toIndex];
   wages[toIndex] = wages[toIndex]^wages[fromIndex];

   payrate[fromIndex] = payrate[fromIndex]^payrate[toIndex];
   payrate[toIndex] = payrate[toIndex]^payrate[fromIndex];

   hours[fromIndex] = hours[fromIndex]^hours[toIndex];
   hours[toIndex] = hours[toIndex]^hours[fromIndex];

}


void bubbleSort(long empId[],int hours[],double payRate[],double wages[],int size)   
{
bool swap; 
int index; 

do
{
    swap = false; 
    for (int count = 0; count < (size - 1); count++)
    {
        if (wages[count] > wages [count + 1])
        {
            swaphelper( emp , wages , pirate , hours , count , count+1); // can be abstracted to a struct
            swap = true; 
        }
    }

} while (swap); 
}
```